# Bloquear Tecla F5 na aplicação

Tags: java, banco-de-dados

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Java Web, e constatei que após realizar um cadastro e teclar <kbd>F5</kbd> as informações ficam duplicadas, apenas o ID que não duplica porque é serial.
Alguém pode me ajudar, se é possível bloquear o <kbd>F5</kbd>. Obrigada

Comment: ola, pode serm ``javascript``?

Comment: Como indicado pelo Maicon, existem vários problemas além da tecla F5 (clicar em refresh, enter na barra de endereços). A lógica deve ser alterada além de só bloquear a tecla F5. Poste seu código para podermos ajudar mais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Leticia**, versão javascript:

```js
document.onkeydown = fkey;
document.onkeypress = fkey
document.onkeyup = fkey;

var foiPressionado = false;

function fkey(e){
        e = e || window.event;
       if( foiPressionado ) return; 

        if (e.keyCode == 116) {
             alert("F5 pressionado");
            foiPressionado = true;
        }else {
            alert("Proibido");
        }
 }
```

**Demo**

**https://jsfiddle.net/felipe_douradinho/dv37ae95/2/embedded/result/**

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é criar uma função javascript pra impedir que ele aperte a tecla correspondente ao <kbd>F5</kbd>

```js
function desabilitaF5(e) { 
  if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) 
    e.preventDefault(); 
};

$(document).on("keydown", desabilitaF5); // com jQuery
//document.addEventListener("keydown", desabilitaF5); // com JavaScript
```

O problema disso é que ainda assim ele pode ir com o mouse e clicar no `atualizar` do navegador. Pra resolver isso você teria que criar um mecanismo pra verificar se o usuário que enviou a requisição, está enviando os mesmos dados do último `INSERT` que você fez e bloquear.